# I am trying to join 3 tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull back data from 3 tables and this is the code that I am using.  However it does not give an error message, it just returns empty rows.  I am using SQL Server Mgmt Studio

```
select l.user_name, l.display_name, m.group_name, m.GROUP_ID
from dbo.groups m, dbo.group_members n, dbo.users l
where l.user_id = n.member_group_id
and n.group_id = m.group_id
```

Comment: You have data?  You are getting rows

Comment: Is it possible to see your table structure. When you don't get any rows back it means your query doesn't match any rows but without seeing your table structure it's not easy to say why

Comment: change `l.user_id = n.member_group_id` to `l.user_id = n.member_user_id`

Comment: Please, add data structure and some data sample.

Comment: Thanks Gordy!  That worked

Comment: @gordy: The answer section is down below.

Comment: Generally it is a bad practice to use associative joins.  Use explicit OUTER or INNER joins that show your intent directly.  By doing so, it would likely have been really clear to you where your mistake had been here.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You are missing inner join statements.

```
select l.user_name, l.display_name, m.group_name, m.GROUP_ID
from dbo.groups m
inner join dbo.group_members n on n.primarykey = m.foreignkey
inner join dbo.users l on on l.primarykey = m.foreignkey
where l.user_id = n.member_group_id
and n.group_id = m.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordy's solution worked..Thanks again

//

change l.user_id = n.member_group_id to l.user_id = n.member_user_id